# How to figure out the height of a div for mobile browser

Tags: html, mobile, css, mobile-browser

I am trying to recreate the page http://www.rexonmedia.com/test/sohalo/images/html5_simpletest.png using HTML 5 and CSS3 but  having trouble with the height. I measured the height of the footer with is 50px. It looks okay on the regular browser but on the mobile browser it looks really small. What am I missing here. Is there a tag or equation that will show it properly on the mobile browser?

HTML
    
    
    
    
    Test

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style/reset.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style/styles.css" />

<meta name="description" content="The HTML5 Herald">
<meta name="author" content="SitePoint">
<!--[if lt IE 9]>
  <script src="http://html5shiv.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script>
  <![endif]-->
</head>
<body>
<header> </header>
<div id="wrap">
<div id="main"> </div>
</div>
<footer> </footer>
</body>
</html>
```

CSS

```
@charset "UTF-8";
/* CSS Document */



header{
    width:100%;
    height:50px;
    background-color:#113b44;
}

#wrap {
    min-height: 100%;
}

#main {

}

footer {
    position:fixed;
    bottom:0px;
    width:100%;
    background-color:#231f20;
    height:50px;
}
```

Comment: Figured it out. The meta tag <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width; initial-scale=1.0; maximum-scale=1.0; user-scalable=0;" />
 and making every container width 100% did the trick.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try pt instead of px in CSS height?   This is a pretty common problem in web development.  A solution is detecting the users screen resolution and including an 'mobile' style sheet.